# TypeError: myParser.MessageParser is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, constructor, typeerror, subclassing

I'm trying to write a custom parser for use with the serialport library. I've followed the example of the parsers provided with the library, but when I try to instantiate I get the captioned error.

I'm stuck on this and can't find anything. I'm a JS beginner, so likely I'm missing something obvious. Code is being executed from the command line as: 'C:> Node speed.js'.

In msgParser.js:

```
const Buffer = require('safe-buffer').Buffer;
const Transform = require('stream').Transform;

module.exports = class MessageParser extends Transform 
{
    constructor() 
    {
        //options = options || {};
        super();

        this.delimiter = 0xA4;
        this.msg = Buffer.alloc(0);
        this.bytesNeeded = 0;
    }

    _transform(chunk, encoding, callback) 
    {
         //etc
    }

    _flush(cb) 
    {
        this.push(this.msg);
        this.msg = Buffer.alloc(0);
        cb();
    }

};
```

In speed.js:

```
/* jshint esversion: 6 */
/* jshint node: true */
'use strict';
const config = require('./config.json');
const serial = require('serialport');
const myParser = require('./msgParser.js');

const msgParser = new myParser.MessageParser();
const monitor = new serial.parsers.Readline({ delimiter: '\r\n' });

var port = new serial(config.serialPort, { baudRate: config.baudRate, highwatermark: 1024 });

port.pipe(msgParser).pipe(monitor);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're defining the entire export not a property on the export. This will work.

```
const MessageParser = require('./msgParser.js');
const msgParser = new MessageParser();
```

Should work.